# Confusion about generic return type in Java

Tags: java, generics

Generic has always been a topic of fear for me.
Recently I came across a code snippet while learning the retrofit in Android

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

Can anybody, in depth, explain me meaning of this  `<S>S` part to me ?
Especially why the `<S>` is added to the left of S ?

Comment: The `S` in the brackets is the type declaration. Just like you can't use a variable without declaring it, you can't use a type parameter before declaring it. The next `S` is the return type, which is the same as whatever `Class` you pass into the method.

Comment: What if <S> on left of S was not there ?

Comment: In that case, there would have to be an actual type named `S` in the program. Such as `class S` or `interface S`.

Comment: As I said, it's like trying to use a variable without declaring it. It won't compile.

Comment: Without the `<S>` it would not be a generic method.  `S` would need to be the name of a real type.  The caller would need to provide the `Class` object representing that specific type as the method argument, and the return value would (need to) be an instance of that specific type.

Answer (score 1):

The `<S>` tells the compiler that when it is compiling calls to the method, there will be some type that the compiler will have to infer, which is the type that the method is going to operate on.

The `S` is the return value of the method, as usual. It tells the compiler what type will be returned.

`Class<S>` defines the type of the parameter. For instance, if the type happens to be `String`, the parameter would be of type `Class<String>` (which can also be written as `String.class`, a form you may be more accustomed to seeing it in.)

For example, if you had a class, `CustomerService`, and you were to call the method like this: `createService(CustomerService.class)`, since the type of `CustomerService.class` is `Class<CustomerService>` and the parameter is `Class<S>`, the compiler would infer that `S` is `CustomerService` and thus would expect the method to return that.

Answer (score 0):

The `<S>` is the list of type parameters for the method (only one in this case).  The presence of a type-parameter list makes this a generic method.  Within the method header and body, the symbol `S` represents the type argument associated with a given invocation of that method, whether inferred or specified explicitly.

A generic method's return type appears between the type-parameter list and the method name.  In the example, this is given as `S`, the type parameter, so the return type of a given invocation of the method is that invocation's type argument.  Typically, it would be inferred from the method argument (and that's exactly the purpose of providing a `Class<S>` as a method parameter).

Without the type-parameter list (`<S>`), the method would be an ordinary one, not a generic one.  In that case, `S` would need to be the name of a specific type that the compiler could resolve.  The argument would need to be the particular `Class` object representing type `S`, and the method would (need to) return an instance of type `S`.

The main difference is that with a generic method, all those properties are determined on a per-invocation basis by the context of the invocation, whereas with the ordinary method, they are determined once, at compile time, for all invocations.  Of course, the devil is in the details.  The generic method needs a way to deliver on the requirement of returning an instance of a type specified at runtime.  The argument of type `Class<S>` can help, and more generally, a generic method that returns an instance of its type argument can do so only by relying on its arguments or by returning `null`.

Also, method genericity is orthogonal to class / interface genericity.

- Classes that are not generic can have generic methods.  In fact, this is the situation for most generic methods.
- Generic classes can have ordinary methods, and that's the norm.  That a method uses *its class'* type parameters does not make that method generic.
- And generic classes can also have generic methods.  You can recognize such generic methods, as always, because they bear their own type-parameter lists.

Answer (score 0):

generics are just variables, except, these variables are references to **types** whereas 'normal' variables reference **values**.

Given:

```
Number n;
n = Integer.valueOf(5);
System.out.println(n);
```

A few things are happening:

1. `Number n;` *declares a new variable*. It says to the system: I decree there is some variable. Variables aren't values (they **hold** a value, a nuanced difference - `Integer.valueOf(5)`, that *is* a value). This variable furthermore has a limitation assigned to it: It must only ever be holding a value that has the property that it was created either as `new Number()`, or as `new Something()`, where `Something` has `Number` somewhere in its type hierarchy. That last bit is very important (after all, `Number` is abstract; `new Number()` is not possible at all).
2. In stark contrast, the second and third line do not *declare* anything. They merely *use* what has already been declared.

**Type variables work the same way**.

Given:

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
     return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

The `<S>` part **declares** a new type variable. it is the typevar equivalent of writing `Object s;`. It declares a variable without assigning any value to it. If you had tried to write:

```
public static S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) { ... }
```

The compiler would complain exactly the same way it complains when you write:

```
void foo() {
 n = 5; // n? What is n? I have no idea what is going on!
}
```

You have to declare before you can use them. Just `<S>` says there is no limit - it's short for `<S extends Object>`, and every ref type extends Object, hence, S can be anything (except primitives - generics and primitives don't currently (JDK21 and older) work together, maybe in some future java version that will change though).

You could have just as easily written:

```
public <S extends Number> createService(Class<S> serviceClass) { .. }
```

Which is just fine; that restricts `S` to refer only to either `Number`, or `Integer`, or `Double`, or any other type that has `Number` in its list of supertypes (interface *or* class, does not matter).

Now, things get a little different. The one that *sets* this variable is the caller, *not* you. The caller decides what S is. You (the one writing the method) merely specifies the type restriction. In that sense it's exactly like a method parameter, where you (the method author) decide what type it has to be, but the caller picks the value for it.

And that is not exactly the right 'view' - at runtime you can't ask what S is (the 'values' of typevars are erased by the compiler; in the class file it just isn't there, at all).

Given that generics are erased, the only real point to generics is **to link things**. Imagine I want a method that simply prints the int value of any number, and then just returns it, i.e. that I can write:

```
Integer i = printAsInt(Integer.valueOf(5));
```

Note how this is different from:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);
printAsInt(i);
```

Because that second snippet is two lines - to 'compress it down to one', we need the `printNumber` method to not just print that number, it also needs to *return the parameter verbatim*. We can trivially write this, of course:

```
public Number printAsInt(Number n) {
  System.out.println(n.intValue());
  return n;
}
```

But this actually doesn't work! If we try to now write:

```
Integer i = printAsInt(Integer.valueOf(5));
```

`javac` will complain: The `printAsInt` method guarantees that it returns a `Number`. Yes, **we** can see it returns its input, but you are free to change that method's contents later on and assuming you stick to the contract that is not considered 'backwards incompatible' (and 'return any Number' is part of the contract, not necessarily 'return the input').

So, we want a way in the type system to link things: To say, the type of the parameter is.. dunno. But whatever it is, the return type? It's the same type.

And hence, this is the right way to write `printAsInt`:

```
public <N extends Number> N printAsInt(N number) {
  System.out.println(number.intValue());
  return number;
}
```

Yes, that means if you use a declared type var 0 or 1 times total, it's a hack or a useless typevar. Needs to show up in at least 2 places. (printAsInt has it in 2 places: Return type, and type of its parameter).

### Your snippet

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
     return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

So now we know how to read this thing:

*Caller, you can call this method by picking some type (any type is fine - S has no bounds), as well as picking a value for the only parameter I have. We linked some things: Whatever you picked for S? You need to provide a value whose type is `Class<S>` - in practice, if you pick `String`, the only thing you can pass is `String.class`. I will return - the type you picked*.

### Where to declare typevars

You can legally declare a typevar in one of two places:

- On a type declaration - looks like `public class Foo<T extends Number> {}` - here T declares a new type var, and it exists for all non-static methods and fields (and even non-static inner classes) defined anywhere inside that type.
- On a method or constructor - looks like `public <T extends Number> void foo()` - exists only for that method.

Your snippet is an example of the second bullet. Something like java's own `java.util.List` is an example of the first - it is declared as `public interface List<E> {}` and that `E` shows up everywhere - `add(E elem)`, `E get(int idx)`, `Iterator<E> iterator()`, and many more.

### Care - variance!

Java itself is covariant. That means a type is a perfectly fine standin for any of its supertypes. If you have a method `void foo(Number n) {}` you are free to call it with `foo(i)` where `i` is declared as `Integer i;` - because Integer is a perfectly fine standin for Number as Number is a supertype.

**Generics are not like that**. Because math/universe. For example, given a `List<Number>`, that has a method `.add(Number n)`, and we just said that this means I can invoke `.add(someInteger)`. And thus also `.add(someDouble)`. But, if I can write:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> numbers = ints; // same list!
numbers.add(Double.valueOf(5.5));
Integer i = ints.get(0);
```

then.. that code makes no sense, at all. There is only one list here (count the `new` - there is just the one `new`), just, 2 vars that both refer to the same list. I add a `Double`... to... a list.. of... ints. Uhoh. That's not right. That last line is non-sensical!

That's why the above *does not compile*. Because unlike 'normal' java, the stuff within the `<>` is **invariant**. If you need `Number`, only `Number` will do, not any subtype of Number.

This is incredibly restrictive - imagine you want to write a method that takes in a list of numbers and all you do is print them out. If we write:

```
public void printAllAsInt(List<Number> list) {
  for (Number n : list) System.out.println(n.intValue());
}
```

then we indeed cannot write:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
printAllAsInt(list);
```

Because generics are invariant, and thus a `List<Integer>` is not an acceptable type to pass to a method that takes a `List<Number>` for the same reason you can't pass an `JLabel` to a method that takes a `File` object - completely different, unrelated types.

But that's annoying - our code would work just fine for any number (all numbers have an `intValue()` method, even doubles). You can write that:

```
void printAllAsInt(List<? extends Number> list) {
  ...
}
```

Now you *can* pass a `List<Integer>` to it. `? extends` means: "I want covariance", and `? super` means: "I want contravariance". The compiler protects you: You **cannot** invoke `.add` on a `List<? extends Number>`. At all.

`List<? extends Number>` does **not** mean "A list that can contain numbers - any kinds of numbers". After all, `List<Number>` already means precisely that. No, `List<? extends Number>` means: A list that contains... well, I don't actually know. It's certainly restricted to.. something. I do know that whatever the restriction is, it's either `Number`, or `Integer`, or `Double`, or any other type that extends Number. Thus, calling `.get(idx)` on this list guarantees at the very least something assignable to a variable of type `Number` falls out. But, `.add()` is just straight up uncallable, given that I have no idea - could be a `List<Double>`, could be a `List<Integer>` - no value is *both* a `Double` **and** an `Integer` at the same time, so NOTHING can be passed to `add`. Well, except, literally, `null`, which is all types, but that's mostly useless.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is newer than the originating *Java* syntax.

*Java* ran for several issues before implementing the *[Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)* interface, which was introduced in *[Java SE 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)*.

In addition to this, *Java* was founded on the same syntax as *[C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))*, with the aim to offer an easy transition from *C* to *Java*.

Hence, the only way to correctly define generic-type parameters would be to create a new syntax.

You can review *generic* method syntax, at the following link.
*[Generic Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Generics (Updated))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)*.

Essentially, it is stating that, within the method there will be a type *S* object.
So the compiler doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Why is the history relevant?

Comment: To answer the question.

Comment: The question was about the meaning of the syntax, not how and when it was introduced.

Comment: That's great, write an answer.